# Search and replace text in a string

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I use the code below to search and replace a part of a text in a string. It works fine for almost 97 % of the replacements but not when one string that is supposed to be replaced is identical with another part of the string. Is there a straightforward method to avoid this?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To Worksheets("table1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Worksheets("table1").Range("H:H").Replace What:=Worksheets("table2").Range("A" & i), Replacement:=Worksheets("table2").Range("B" & i), LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

**Important:** The delimiter is not always **","**. It can also be any combination blank space(s) with a comma. Examples:

**", "

" ,"

" , "**

Comment: In the example, if string is col H and replacement is col B, what/where is column A ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, why don't you: 1. Trim within the code so you can split by commas 2. Do a regex for the array elements and check before a character comes in (that's not a letter) only for the portion that you want and if it's true, replace it

Answer (score 7):

This is what is called a [False Positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives). If the delimiter is going to be always `,` then split the string. Do the replace and then join them again.

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code. If you still have questions then simply ask.

```
Option Explicit

'~~> This is the delimiter. Change as applicable
Private Const Delim As String = ","

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsTblA As Worksheet
    Dim wsTblB As Worksheet
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Dim ArTable1 As Variant
    Dim ArTable2 As Variant
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set wsTblA = Worksheets("Table2")
    Set wsTblB = Worksheets("Table1")
    
    '~~> Get the values in Col A and B from Sheet Table2 in an array
    With wsTblA
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        ArTable2 = .Range("A2:B" & lRow).Value2
    End With
    
    '~~> Get the values in Col H from Sheet Table1 in an array
    With wsTblB
        lRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        ArTable1 = .Range("H2:H" & lRow).Value2
    End With
    
    '~~> Loop through the array
    For i = LBound(ArTable2) To UBound(ArTable2)
        For j = LBound(ArTable1) To UBound(ArTable1)
            '~~> Check if the search string is present
            If InStr(1, ArTable1(j, 1), ArTable2(i, 1), vbTextCompare) Then
                '~~> If it is present then attempt a replace
                ArTable1(j, 1) = ReplaceText(ArTable1(j, 1), ArTable2(i, 1), ArTable2(i, 2))
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    '~~> Write the array back to the worksheet
    wsTblB.Range("H2").Resize(UBound(ArTable1), 1).Value = ArTable1
End Sub

'~~> Function to split the text and then compare. If exact match, then replace
Private Function ReplaceText(CellValue As Variant, ReplaceWhat As Variant, ReplaceWith As Variant) As String
    Dim tmpAr As Variant
    Dim ReplacedText As String
    Dim k As Long
    
    '~~> Split the test using the delimiter
    tmpAr = Split(CellValue, Delim)
    
    '~~> If exact match, then replace
    For k = LBound(tmpAr) To UBound(tmpAr)
        If UCase(Trim(tmpAr(k))) = UCase(Trim(ReplaceWhat)) Then
            tmpAr(k) = ReplaceWith
        End If
    Next k
    
    '~~> Rejoin using delimiter
    ReplacedText = Join(tmpAr, Delim)
    ReplaceText = ReplacedText
End Function
```

**Sheets TABLE2**

[image]

**Sheets TABLE1**

[image]

**Sheets TABLE1 OUTPUT**

[image]

**EDIT**

> Thank you for your wonderful solution. Problem is the delimiter is not always ",". It can also be a blank space " ". Problem using a blank space as additional delimiter might be the case that each element of the string e. g. "4711 Text_A" always has a blank space after the first 4 chars. – D3merzel 44 mins ago

In that case, you can take another approach. The text can appear in 3 positions. At the begining (`TEXT & Delim`), in the middle (`Delim & TEXT & Delim`) and in the end (`Delim & TEXT`)

Can you try the below code. I have not extensively tested it. If you find a scenario where it doesn't work then share it, I will tweak the code.

```
Option Explicit

'~~> This is the delimiter. Change as applicable
Private Const Delim As String = " "

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsTblA As Worksheet
    Dim wsTblB As Worksheet
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Dim ArTable1 As Variant
    Dim ArTable2 As Variant
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set wsTblA = Worksheets("Table2")
    Set wsTblB = Worksheets("Table1")
    
    '~~> Get the values in Col A and B from Sheet Table2 in an array
    With wsTblA
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        ArTable2 = .Range("A2:B" & lRow).Value2
    End With
    
    '~~> Get the values in Col H from Sheet Table1 in an array
    With wsTblB
        lRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        ArTable1 = .Range("H2:H" & lRow).Value2
    End With
    
    '~~> Loop through the array
    For i = LBound(ArTable2) To UBound(ArTable2)
        For j = LBound(ArTable1) To UBound(ArTable1)
            '~~> Check if the search string is present
            If Left(ArTable1(j, 1), Len(ArTable2(i, 1) & Delim)) = ArTable2(i, 1) & Delim Then
                ArTable1(j, 1) = Replace(ArTable1(j, 1), ArTable2(i, 1) & Delim, ArTable2(i, 2) & Delim)
            ElseIf InStr(1, ArTable1(j, 1), Delim & ArTable2(i, 1) & Delim, vbTextCompare) Then
                ArTable1(j, 1) = Replace(ArTable1(j, 1), Delim & ArTable2(i, 1) & Delim, Delim & ArTable2(i, 2) & Delim)
            ElseIf Right(ArTable1(j, 1), Len(Delim & ArTable2(i, 1))) = Delim & ArTable2(i, 1) Then
                ArTable1(j, 1) = Replace(ArTable1(j, 1), Delim & ArTable2(i, 1), Delim & ArTable2(i, 2))
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    '~~> Write the array back to the worksheet
    wsTblB.Range("H2").Resize(UBound(ArTable1), 1).Value = ArTable1
End Sub
```

**Sheets TABLE2**

[image]

**Sheets TABLE1**

[image]

**Sheets TABLE1 OUTPUT**

[image]

**EDIT**

The above code handles all the ranges in one go! But if the code is too overwhelming (*which it should not be*), the above code can be reduced to a function to handle say individual string. One can use this function to check if the replace is happening correctly using a **single** string. For example

```
Debug.Print SidRepcl("bbb b_ bb b__ ccc_ bb b_ ccc", "ccc_", "ccc", " ")
```

**Output**: bbb b_ bb b__ ccc bb b_ ccc

As I mentioned earlier, all my codes above are based on the below logic

**Logic**: The text can appear in 3 positions. At the begining (`TEXT & Delim`), in the middle (`Delim & TEXT & Delim`) and in the end (`Delim & TEXT`)

```
Option Explicit

Function SidRepcl(txt As String, srch As String, repl As String, Delim As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RetVal As String: RetVal = txt
    
    '~~> Check if the search string is present
    If Left(txt, Len(srch & Delim)) = srch & Delim Then
        RetVal = Replace(txt, srch & Delim, repl & Delim)
    ElseIf InStr(1, txt, Delim & srch & Delim, vbTextCompare) Then
        RetVal = Replace(txt, Delim & srch & Delim, Delim & repl & Delim)
    ElseIf Right(txt, Len(Delim & srch)) = Delim & srch Then
        RetVal = Replace(txt, Delim & srch, Delim & repl)
    End If

    SidRepcl = RetVal
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful solution. Problem is the delimiter is not always ",". It can also be a blank space " ". Problem using a blank space as additional delimiter might be the case that each element of the string e. g. "4711 Text_A" always has a blank space after the first 4 chars.

Comment: I have updated the post.Check the edit. You may have to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: Helpful & instructive approaches :-) Fyi Posted an alternative changing the punctuation delimiter logic completely. @SiddharthRout

Comment: @D3merzel: Did you see the edit?

Comment: It doesn't work. Some elements in the strings are replaced others not.

Comment: @D3merzel: Can you please give me couple of examples?

Comment: @SiddharthRout possibly a) the original example `"4711 TEXT_A, 4710 TEXT_B, 4711 TEXT_AA, 4711 TEXT_AB"`: should replace the 1st part, b) entire input text = search string: should be replaced 100%; modifications like `"4711 TEXT_A, 4711 TEXT_A"` without starting delim `" "`? *(Side note: sorry that chat has been deleted)*

Answer (score 5):

### Replace in Delimited Strings

[image]

**Main**

```vb
Sub ReplaceData()

    Const SRC_DELIMITER As String = ","
    Const DST_DELIMITER As String = ", "

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
 
    ' Write the values from the source range to an array.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Table2")
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off AutoFilter
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = sws.Range("A2:B" & sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    Dim Data(): Data = srg.Value
    
    ' Sort the array by length descending so that the longer strings
    ' are first matched to avoid finding shorter strings before longer ones.
    BubbleSortDataByLen Data, 1, True
    
    ' Write the unique values from the array to a dictionary.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = TwoColumnsToDictionary(Data, 1, 2)
    
    ' Write the values from the destination range to an array.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Table1")
    If dws.AutoFilterMode Then dws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off AutoFilter
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = dws.Range("H2", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
    
    Data = drg.Value
    
    ' Replace.
    ReplaceSingleColumnData Data, dict, SRC_DELIMITER, DST_DELIMITER
        
    ' Write back to the range.
    drg.Value = Data
        
    ' Inform
    MsgBox "Data replaced.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Sort**

```vb
Sub BubbleSortDataByLen( _
        ByRef Data() As Variant, _
        ByVal SortColumnIndex As Long, _
        Optional ByVal Descending As Boolean = False)
    
    Dim rLB As Long, rUB As Long: rLB = LBound(Data, 1): rUB = UBound(Data, 1)
    Dim cLB As Long, cUB As Long: cLB = LBound(Data, 2): cUB = UBound(Data, 2)
    
    Dim T, i As Long, j As Long, c As Long, IsNotsorted As Boolean
    
    For i = rLB To rUB - 1
        For j = rLB + 1 To rUB
            If Descending Then
                If Len(CStr(Data(i, SortColumnIndex))) < Len(CStr( _
                    Data(j, SortColumnIndex))) Then IsNotsorted = True
            Else
                If Len(CStr(Data(i, SortColumnIndex))) > Len(CStr( _
                    Data(j, SortColumnIndex))) Then IsNotsorted = True
            End If
            If IsNotsorted Then
                For c = cLB To cUB
                   T = Data(i, c): Data(i, c) = Data(j, c): Data(j, c) = T
                Next c
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Dictionary**

```vb
Function TwoColumnsToDictionary( _
    Data() As Variant, _
    ByVal KeyColumnIndex As Long, _
    ByVal ItemColumnIndex As Long, _
    Optional ByVal MatchCase As Boolean = False) _
As Object
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = IIf(MatchCase, vbBinaryCompare, vbTextCompare)
    
    Dim r As Long, kStr As String
    
    For r = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        kStr = CStr(Data(r, KeyColumnIndex))
        If Len(kStr) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
            ' Use the first occurrences if any duplicates (shouldn't be any).
            If Not dict.Exists(kStr) Then
                dict(kStr) = CStr(Data(r, ItemColumnIndex))
            End If
        End If
    Next r
        
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Set TwoColumnsToDictionary = dict
    
End Function
```

**Replace**

```vb
Sub ReplaceSingleColumnData( _
        ByRef Data() As Variant, _
        ByVal dict As Object, _
        ByVal InDelimiter As String, _
        ByVal OutDelimiter As String)

    Dim r As Long, n As Long
    Dim sStrings() As String, sStr As String
    
    For r = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        sStr = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        If Len(sStr) > 0 Then
            sStrings = Split(sStr, InDelimiter)
            For n = 0 To UBound(sStrings)
                sStr = Application.Trim(sStrings(n)) ' reusing 'sStr'
                If dict.Exists(sStr) Then
                    sStrings(n) = dict(sStr)
                Else
                    sStrings(n) = sStr
                End If
            Next n
            Data(r, 1) = Join(sStrings, OutDelimiter)
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing happens to the data in column "H". Only a window with "Data replaced" pops up.

Comment: In the screenshot, the F column only shows what previously was in column H. If your worksheets aren't in the workbook containing this code, you can't use `ThisWorkbook`. You need to adjust the worksheet names, maybe they need to be switched.

Comment: Do your strings in column `H` of `Table1` have multiple rows per cell? That would be the only reason I could find that nothing has changed after running my code and we would need to implement an additional split by the new line character. Feel free to download a copy of [my file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Wi-7VMo6Ag0UmBxqSHsYTPAOy-8U9MK/view?usp=sharing) from my Google drive.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out again with a copy of your file. The strings don't have multiple rows per cell.

Comment: As you can see, I edited my code on Jan 3rd. Maybe you have a copy of my old code when I wasn't aware of the different delimiters. Also, sorting the strings was not implemented.

Answer (score 5):

**Flexible solution with any combinations of blank space(s) with comma(ta)**

As alternative to Siddharth 's approaches you could change the *logic* by

- 1. splitting the *input text* via the ►**search string** *itself* instead of applying punctuation delimiters like e.g. `", "`, `","` or `" "`;
- 2. checking the last character in the current token and the starting character in each following token to execute replacements.

The following *(edited 2023-01-02)* function **solves** the additional requirements in comment that

> ... the delimiter is not always ",". It can also be a blank space " ". Problem using a blank space as additional delimiter might be the case that each element of the string e. g. "4711 Text_A" always has a blank space after the first 4 chars

by checking only one right or left neighbour character to each contained search string for `" "` or `","` (c.f. returned helper function result `IsMatch = curEndChar Like "[ ,]" And nxtStartChar Like "[ ,]"` *as well as comments to function `TMreplc()`*).

Note that the substitution **logic** doesn't focus only to these evident delimiters but will change input strings like e.g. `"4711 TEXT_A"` also to e.g. `4711 TEXT_A/1`.

```
Function TMreplc(txt As String, srch As String, repl As String) As String
'a) special case: replace entire text if identical to search string
    If txt = srch Then TMreplc = repl: Exit Function
'b) get tokens by splitting via "search string" itself
    Dim tokens: tokens = Split(txt, srch)
    Dim ub   As Long:    ub = UBound(tokens)
'c) remember penultimate item
    Dim mem  As String:  If ub > 0 Then mem = tokens(ub - 1)
'd) check most right token for content
    Dim chk  As Boolean: chk = tokens(ub) = vbNullString
    If chk And ub > 0 Then                       
        tokens(ub - 1) = tokens(ub - 1) & IIf(Len(mem) = 0, srch, repl)
        If ub = 1 And tokens(0) = vbNullString Then tokens(0) = repl
    End If
'e) Check predecessing tokens for substitutability
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To ub - IIf(chk, 2, 1)   ' if no srch finding at all (ignores: 0 To -1)
        tokens(i) = tokens(i) & IIf(IsMatch(tokens, i), repl, srch)
    Next i
'f) return result string
    TMreplc = Join(tokens, vbNullString)
End Function
```

```
Function IsMatch(tokens, ByVal idx) As Boolean
    Dim curEndChar As String
    curEndChar = Right(IIf(idx = 0 And Len(tokens(0)) = 0, " ", "") & tokens(idx), 1)
    Dim nxtStartChar As String: nxtStartChar = Left(tokens(idx + 1), 1)
    
    IsMatch = curEndChar Like "[ ,]" And nxtStartChar Like "[ ,]"
End Function
```

**Output examples**

[image: Output examples]

---

**History**

My first incomplete attempt below tried to include the cited additional requirement by checking only the following character, but  didn't take into account those cases where the search string included preceding characters in the current token. I leave this attempt for *learning purposes*. - *See Siddharth 's helpful comments that pointed me in the right direction*.

*A. First incomplete try*

```
Function replc(txt As String, srch As String, repl As String) As String
'a) split input text into tokens via srch delimiter
    Dim tokens: tokens = Split(txt, srch)
    Dim ub   As Long:    ub = UBound(tokens)
'b) check possible change in last search item     
    Dim chg  As Boolean: chg = tokens(ub) = vbNullString
    If chg Then tokens(ub - 1) = tokens(ub - 1) & repl
'c) modify tokens
    Dim i    As Long
    For i = 0 To ub - IIf(chg, 2, 1)
         Dim nxtStartChar As String: nxtStartChar = Left(tokens(i + 1), 1)
         tokens(i) = IIf(nxtStartChar Like "[ ,]", tokens(i) & repl, tokens(i) & srch)
    Next i
'd) return joined tokens 
    replc = Join(tokens, vbNullString)
End Function
```

---

**Additional note**

It might be instructive, too how I tried to solve the original question (*originally* without the need of a different delimiter than `", "`). Note the 2nd argument in the `Match()` function passed as array of a single string value.

```
Function replc2(txt As String, srch As String, repl As String) As String
    Dim tokens: tokens = Split(txt, ", ")
    Dim mtch:   mtch = Application.Match(tokens, Array(srch), 0)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(mtch)
        If IsNumeric(mtch(i)) Then tokens(i - 1) = repl
    Next i
    replc2 = Join(tokens, ", ")
End Function
```

*B. My second try* *(as of 2022-12-13)* includes a helper function `IsMatch`, but failed on certain scenarios (e.g. if the input txt is 100% identical to the search string - see last edit on top of post); I include it only for comparison reasons to complete **history**:

```
Function replc(txt As String, srch As String, repl As String) As String
Dim tokens: tokens = Split(txt, srch)
Dim i    As Long
Dim ub   As Long: ub = UBound(tokens)
Dim chg  As Boolean: chg = tokens(ub) = vbNullString
If chg Then tokens(ub - 1) = tokens(ub - 1) & repl
For i = 0 To ub - IIf(chg, 2, 1)
    tokens(i) = tokens(i) & IIf(IsMatch(tokens, i), repl, srch)
Next i
replc = Join(tokens, vbNullString)
End Function
```

*Function `IsMatch()` - see top of post*

Comment: Hi T.M. Thank you. Your post helped me find out a small bug in mine which I fixed. BTW splitting on search string itself can also lead to false positive. Here is an example. Let's say the string is `bb b__ bb b_ ccc`. The search string is `bb b_` and the replace text is `bbb`. In such a case your code works. The correct output is `bb b__ bbb ccc`. But if I change the input string to `bbb b_ bb b__ bb b_ ccc`, then your code will fail. The correct output should be `bbb b_ bb b__ bbb ccc` and not `bbbb bb b__ bbb ccc` :)

Comment: Keeping in mind that the text can appear in 3 positions. At the begining (`TEXT & Delim`), in the middle (`Delim & TEXT & Delim`) and in the end (`Delim & TEXT`) . And hence I am using `LEFT()`, `INSTR()` and `RIGHT()` to handle it...

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I appreciate your helpful comments *(btw glad having helped you, too)* & thank you for your valuable hints - will 'digest' them later for a possible edit. @SiddharthRout

Comment: @SiddharthRout fyi Inserted an edit to solve requirements.

Comment: I tried it T.M but it fails on other scenarios. Apologies if you think I am being picky? More than happy to try and assist to solve this on a chat using your method if you wish?

Comment: Thank you again - i'm very interested in your assistance. Would like to continue on a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/250407/split-logic-to-replace-string-sequences-in-excel-vba?tab=conversations)

Comment: @D3merzel a) Would you tell me please examples, as I found no evident bugs? - b) Is it correct that an entire text string "4711 TEXT_A", i.e. 100% identical to the search string would be replaced by "4711 TEXT_A/1"?

Comment: @D3merzel I've added a whole bunch of examples to my post; would you point out where you see another logic?

Answer (score 2):

you may want to stick to the `Range.Replace()` approach as much as possible

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Const delimiter As String = " "
    
    With Worksheets("table2") ' reference the find&replace sheet
        Dim findRng As Range
            Set findRng = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) ' set the range in referenced sheet from column A row 2 down to last not empty row
    End With
    
        With Worksheets("table1") ' reference the data sheet
            With .Range("H1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)) ' reference referenced sheet column "H" range from row 1 down to last not empty row
                                
                '-----------
                'normalize the referenced range values to:
                ' - start with the delimiter
                ' - end with delimiter
                ' - only single spaces
                Dim cel As Range
                For Each cel In .Cells
                    cel.Value = delimiter & WorksheetFunction.Trim(cel.Value) & delimiter
                Next
                
                    .Replace what:=" " & delimiter, replacement:=delimiter, lookat:=xlPart
                    .Replace what:=delimiter & " ", replacement:=delimiter, lookat:=xlPart
                '-----------
                
                    ' do the replacement
                    For Each cel In findRng
                    
                        .Replace what:=cel.Value & delimiter, replacement:=cel.Offset(, 1) & delimiter, _
                                 lookat:=xlPart, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                                 ReplaceFormat:=False
                        
                    Next
                    
                        ' un-normalize the references range
                        ' - remove leading delimiters
                        ' - remove trailing delimiters
                        For Each cel In .Cells
                            cel.Value = Mid$(cel.Value, 2, Len(cel.Value) - 2)
                        Next
            
            End With
        End With

End Sub
```

Where you only have to set the needed delimiter in `Const delimiter As String = " "`

Of course, should you suffer from speed issues, you can switch to a "range to array" approach.

First by acting on the "normalize" and "un-normalize" code sections, only

If necessary, acting on the "do the replacement" section, too

Comment: @D3merzel , did you have any chance to test it?

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, this should work

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i As Integer

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.Intersect(Worksheets("table1").Range("H:H"), Worksheets("table1").UsedRange)
endDel = ", , ,,,"
For Each cell1 In rng
    cell1.Value = cell1.Value & endDel
Next cell1

For i = 2 To Worksheets("table1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row


    Worksheets("table1").Range("H:H").Replace What:=Worksheets("table2").Range("A" & i) & " ", _
    Replacement:=Worksheets("table2").Range("B" & i) & " ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False ', FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    
    Worksheets("table1").Range("H:H").Replace What:=Worksheets("table2").Range("A" & i) & ",", _
    Replacement:=Worksheets("table2").Range("B" & i) & ",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False ', FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    
Next i

rng.Replace What:=endDel, _
Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False ', FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple delimiters, I assume they don't really matter and the string doesn't need to be completely identical apart from the replacements. Assuming that, the easiest way would be just to replace all the possible delimiters, with just one. You can then easily split the string, test each individually then recombine for a standardised string.

> Example code uses `Split(", # ,# , ", "#")` with a delimiter that is not `,` for ease

```
Sub Blah()
    Debug.Print Replacement("A, B , d,e,f,g , h", "e", "G")
End Sub

Function Replacement(strInput As String, ToFind As String, ToReplace As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim DelimArray() As String: DelimArray = Split(", # ,# , ", "#")
    
    For i = LBound(DelimArray) To UBound(DelimArray)
        strInput = Replace(strInput, DelimArray(i), ",")
    Next i
    
    Dim TextArray() As String: TextArray = Split(strInput, ",")
    For i = LBound(TextArray) To UBound(TextArray)
        If TextArray(i) = ToFind Then TextArray(i) = ToReplace
    Next i
    
    Replacement = Join(TextArray, ",")
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:** The *[Range.Replace method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace)* generates unreliable results under the following conditions:

- The strings to be replaced are also part of other strings.
- Strings in the target range have multiple delimiters.
- The strings to be replaced contain one or more of the delimiters.

**Data:**

[image]

| Old (What) | New (Replacement) |
| --- | --- |
| `4711 TEXT_A` | `4711 TEXT_A/1` |
| `4710 TEXT_B` | `4710 TEXT_B/1` |

| String |
| --- |
| `4711 TEXT_A 4710 TEXT_B 4711 TEXT_AA,4710 TEXT_BB , 4711 TEXT_A , 4710 TEXT_B,4711 TEXT_AA, 4710 TEXT_BB, 4711 TEXT_A,4710 TEXT_B, 4711 TEXT_AA, 4710 TEXT_BB` |

The string above presents all the conditions previously mentioned:
[image]

[image]

**Solution Proposed:**
This problem can be solved using the **Range_Replace_With_MultiDelimiters** procedure:

**Syntax**
**Range_Replace_With_MultiDelimiters** *(`rTarget`, `aDelimiters`, `aOldNew`, [`blIncludeFormulas`])*

**Parameters**
[image]

**Remarks**
Delimiters that contain other delimiters must be placed in the array before the delimiters it contains, e.g.:
[image]

**Variables:**
[image]

**Method:**
1 - **Mask all `sOld` strings to be replaced:** As the strings to be replaced may contain one or more of the delimiters; when we try to standardize the delimiters, the `sOld` strings contained in the target strings will be affected, particularly when the delimiter is  {space} therefore we need to modify *(Mask)* the `sOld` strings before standardizing the delimiters.
To do this we define a one-character constant to be used as a *Mask Character*:

```
Const kMsk As String = "‡"
```

This character must not be present in the `rTarget` range, nor in any `sNew` string.
The `sOld` will be *masked* using the format `‡i‡`, where `i` (position of `sOld` in the `aOldNew` array) is wrapped with the *Mask Character* `‡`.

[image]

2 - **Standardize the Delimiters:** Define a one-character constants to be used as *Standard Delimiter*:

```
Const kChr As String = "§"   '(ASCII code 167)
```

This character must not be present in the `rTarget` range, nor in any `sNew` string.
Then convert all delimiters to a *Standard Delimiter Index* using the format `§i§`, where `i` (position of the delimiter in the array) is wrapped by the *Standard Delimiter* `§`.

This is the standardizing formula:

```
= "§" & SUBSTITUTE( … SUBSTITUTE( rTarget, aDelimiters(1), "§1§" ) … , aDelimiters(n), "§n§") & "§"
```

After the entire replacement process is completed, all delimiters will be reset to their original value. This is the reset formula:

```
= SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( … SUBSTITUTE( rTarget, "§1§", aDelimiters(1) ), … , "§n§", aDelimiters(n) ), "§", TEXT(,) )
```

These formulas will be created by the function: **Range_Replace_ƒDelimiters_Formula** and applied to the `rTarget` using the *[Application.Evaluate method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate)*.

[image]

3 - **Replace *masked* `sOld` strings with `sNew` string:** Before replacing the *masked* `sOld` strings with the corresponding `sNew` string, we need to wrap both *masked* `sOld` strings and the `sNew` strings with the *Standard Delimiter* constant previously defined:

```
sOld = kChr & kMsk & lIdx & kMsk & kChr    '[kMsk & lIdx & kMsk] is masked sOld 
sNew = kChr & aOldNew(lIdx, 2) & kChr
```

[image]

4 - **Replace `Mask` strings with `sOld` string:** Notice that as we wrapped the *masked* `sOld` string before replacing when the `sOld` string was contained in another string it was not replaced as it did not match the wrapped *masked* `sOld` string, achieving the expected result. Now we need to replace back the remaining *masked* `sOld` strings with the original `sOld` strings where partial matches within a larger string happened.

[image]

5 - **Reset the delimiters:** Replace the *Standard Delimiter Index* back to each original delimiter, using the formula mentioned (step 2). This step could also be used to reset the original delimiters to a *standard delimiter*, however, as the list of delimiters includes the   {space} it’s advisable not doing it.

[image]

The results returned by the **Range_Replace_With_MultiDelimiters** procedure mathed the expected results:

[image]

**Procedures:**

```
Sub Search_and_Replace_Text()
Dim aDelimiters() As Variant
    aDelimiters = Array( _
        " , ", _
        " ,", _
        ", ", _
        ",", _
        " ")

Dim rTarget As Range, aOldNew() As Variant
Dim sWsh As String, sRng As String, sFml As String

    Rem Set array with strings to be replaced (Old\New)
    sWsh = "Table2"
    sRng = "A:B"
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sWsh).Range(sRng)

        Rem Activate target worksheet (needed to apply the Application.Evaluate method)
        Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1

        With .Cells(2, 1).Resize(-1 + .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 2)
            sFml = "=UNIQUE(FILTER(" & .Address _
                    & ",(" & .Columns(1).Address & "<>TEXT(,))))"
            aOldNew = Application.Evaluate(sFml)

    End With: End With

    Rem Set range to apply the replace method
    sWsh = "Table1"
    sRng = "H:H"
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sWsh).Range(sRng)
        Set rTarget = Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Call Range_Replace_With_MultiDelimiters(rTarget, aDelimiters, aOldNew)

    End Sub

Private Sub Range_Replace_With_MultiDelimiters( _
    ByVal rTarget As Range, aDelimiters() As Variant, aOldNew() As Variant, _
    Optional blIncludeFormulas As Boolean)

Rem Uncomment the lines the start with [':]
Rem to have in the Immediate Window a record of each step perfomed by the procedure

Const kChr As String = "§"
Const kMsk As String = "‡"

Dim rArea As Range
Dim sOld As String, sNew As String, lIdx As Long
Dim sFmlA As String, sFmlB As String
Dim sFml As String, aValues As Variant

    Rem Built Delimiters Formula - Standardization & Reset
    sFmlA = Range_Replace_ƒDelimiters_Formula(aDelimiters, kChr)
    sFmlB = Range_Replace_ƒDelimiters_Formula(aDelimiters, kChr, True)
': Debug.Print vbLf; "Built Delimiters Formula - Standardization & Reset"
': Debug.Print "Standardization: "; vbLf; "sFmlA: "; sFmlA
': Debug.Print "Reset: "; vbLf; "sFmlB: "; sFmlB

    Rem Exclude Formulas from Target range
    If Not (blIncludeFormulas) Then
        With rTarget
            Set rTarget = Union(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks), _
                                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23))
    End With: End If

    With rTarget

        Rem Activate target range worksheet (needed to apply the Application.Evaluate method)
        Application.Goto .Worksheet.Cells(1), 1

        For Each rArea In .Areas
            With rArea

                Rem Replace Old string To Mask string
': Debug.Print vbLf; "Replace Old To Mask"
': Debug.Print vbTab; "Old"; Tab(21); "New"
                For lIdx = 1 To UBound(aOldNew)

                    sOld = aOldNew(lIdx, 1)
                    sNew = kMsk & lIdx & kMsk
': Debug.Print vbTab; sOld; Tab(21); sNew

                    .Replace What:=sOld, Replacement:=sNew, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

                Next

                Rem Standardize Delimiters
                sFml = Replace(sFmlA, "#RNG", .Address(0, 0))
                aValues = Application.Evaluate(sFml)
                .Value2 = aValues
': Debug.Print vbLf; "Standardize Delimiters"
': Debug.Print "Fml: "; sFml

                Rem Replace Mask string To New string
': Debug.Print vbLf; "Replace Mask To New"
': Debug.Print vbTab; "Old"; Tab(21); "New"
                For lIdx = 1 To UBound(aOldNew)

                    sOld = kChr & kMsk & lIdx & kMsk & kChr
                    sNew = kChr & aOldNew(lIdx, 2) & kChr
': Debug.Print vbTab; sOld; Tab(21); sNew

                    .Replace What:=sOld, Replacement:=sNew, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

                Next

                Rem Replace Mask string To Old string
': Debug.Print vbLf; "Replace Mask To Old"
': Debug.Print vbTab; "Old"; Tab(21); "New"
                For lIdx = 1 To UBound(aOldNew)

                    sOld = kMsk & lIdx & kMsk
                    sNew = aOldNew(lIdx, 1)
': Debug.Print vbTab; sOld; Tab(21); sNew

                    .Replace What:=sOld, Replacement:=sNew, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

                Next

                Rem Reset Delimiters
                sFml = Replace(sFmlB, "#RNG", .Address(0, 0))
                aValues = Application.Evaluate(sFml)
                .Value2 = aValues
': Debug.Print vbLf; "Reset Delimiters"
': Debug.Print "Fml: "; sFml

        End With: Next: End With

    End Sub

Private Function Range_Replace_ƒDelimiters_Formula( _
    aDelimiters() As Variant, sChr As String, Optional blReset As Boolean) As String

Dim sOld As String, sNew As String
Dim sFml As String
Dim vItem As Variant, bItem As Byte

    Rem Separators
    For Each vItem In aDelimiters

        Rem Separators Old & New
        bItem = 1 + bItem
        sOld = IIf(blReset, sChr & bItem & sChr, vItem)
        sNew = IIf(blReset, vItem, sChr & bItem & sChr)

        Rem Built Formula - Delimiters Array
        Select Case bItem
        Case 1:     sFml = "SUBSTITUTE(#RNG,""" & sOld & """,""" & sNew & """)"
        Case Else:  sFml = "SUBSTITUTE(" & sFml & ",""" & sOld & """,""" & sNew & """)"
        End Select

    Next

    Rem Built Formula - Delimiters Character
    Select Case blReset
    Case True:  sFml = "=SUBSTITUTE(" & sFml & ",""" & sChr & """,TEXT(,))"
    Case Else:  sFml = "= """ & sChr & """&" & sFml & "&""" & sChr & """"
    End Select

    Range_Replace_ƒDelimiters_Formula = sFml

    End Function
```